# PyBrain library in parallel achitecture

Tags: python, parallel-processing, neural-network, pybrain

Is there someone who knows if pybrain works in parallel architecture? If it doesn't, which library is avaliable to work with Artificial Neural Network in multi-core processor?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You could try http://deeplearning.net/software/pylearn2/ -- it's written using Theano and so can run on multicore or GPU.

Answer (score 0):

What you've asked depends on the task, but scikit-optimize is able to run in parallel using the ask-and-tell interface.

```
P = <parameter space>
optimizer = Optimizer(P)

while True:
    X = optimizer.ask(num_args=8)
    # X now has eight permutations of the parameter space
    Y = wait_for_parallel_evaluate(objective, X)
    # Y now has a list of results for those permutations
    optimizer.tell(X, Y)
    # optimizer uses the results to decide on what parameters it should try next
```

Instead of having this dedicated loop, you can also serialize optimizer using its dump function and bring it back to call tell on every parallel result and serialize it back.